# ?attr/xxx and inherits style seem not to be reconized in android

Tags: android, xml

I have an Android App and a linked Module

In my Module i have an attr.xml file that defines custom tags

```
<declare-styleable name="CoreAtttributes">
    <attr name="styleNoActionBar" format="reference"/>
...
```

and a style.xml file that define CoreTheme

```
<style name="CoreTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="styleNoActionBar">@style/CoreTheme.NoActionBar</item>
```

with

```
<style name="CoreTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and in the manifest

```
<application 
    android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/CoreTheme">
....
```

In my App i have an attr.xml file that defines other custom tags and inherits from my CoreAttributes defined previously

```
<declare-styleable name="AppAttributes" parent="@declare-styleable/CoreAtttributes">
    <attr name="other....." format="reference"/>
 ....
```

and a style.xml file that defines AppTheme inherits from CoreTheme

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="CoreTheme">
    <item name="other.....">....</item>
....
```

and in the App Manifest

```
<application
    android:name="......"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme">

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activity.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/home_activity_label"
        style="?attr/styleNoActionBar" <-- HERE ITS NOT RECONIZED !!!
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

And when HomeActivity is launched it raises an error : "This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor" so it seems that the style used by the HomeActivity is not seen ???

Thanks for your help. I've searched a long time without beeing able to find a solution.

Comment: There's no `style` attribute in `<activity>`. Doesn't your IDE hightlight it with warning?

Comment: I've updated to a stable version of android studio and you're right. sytle is hightlighted I don't know if i didn't see the IDE hightlight before but with android:theme in place of style i have the same trouble.

Comment: I've found the issue : So to help others, be carefull when overriding Theme. For instance : <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="CoreTheme"> contains a big error with no warning : The AppTheme.NoActionBar is not a child of AppTheme because parent is CoreTheme. So the inheritance by the name doesn't work. An improvement of Android Studio would be to warn the user in such a case. I've updated my first post